# ArcGIS Online - Perform analysis based on different feature services

Tags: arcgis-online, coronavirus

I am creating a COVID response map and we want to show number of infected/recovered/deaths/testing per % population in each country.

The issue is that the key authoritative source is a feature layer - https://services1.arcgis.com/0MSEUqKaxRlEPj5g/arcgis/rest/services/Coronavirus_2019_nCoV_Cases/FeatureServer/2

I want to use this dynamic service and create a table for mapping that uses https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/a21fdb46d23e4ef896f31475217cbb08_1/data - a polygon of all countries and population (from https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/)

Is this possible in ArcGIS Online?

The population by country can be created as a static file, the key question here is can I then divide population by the covid values dynamically or do I need to do something funky like a import into Google Sheets to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with an Arcade expression, but you may have to save a copy of the "Cases_country" feature layer. This would all depend on how Johns Hopkins is choosing to share their data.

More here on example Arcade expression calculating population density https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/data-management/create-custom-field-calculations-using-arcade-expressions/

There should be a countries polygon file floating around out there with population values.  This would simplify your steps at least. Have you tried looking at other Dashboards and seeing what they're using?